# Update query taking more time than expected in MySQL

Tags: mysql

The below update queries are taking around 40 minutes to update a table that contains around 3.5 million records. The column 'is_updated' contains only 0,1,2 values. Please find the table structure and explain the output. Please let me know if I need to follow any different processes or how can be this resolved. Also please let me know if there are any table structure changes required.
Please someone help me!! The update is taking almost 1 hr now.

```
UPDATE jobs_feed SET is_updated=0 WHERE is_updated IN(1,2);

UPDATE  jobs_feed SET is_deleted=1, job_status=3 ,deleted_on='2022-08-05'  WHERE is_updated = 0 AND is_deleted = 0
```

[Explain output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZzmGn.png)

```
    CREATE TABLE `jobs_feed` (
  `id` INT (11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `jobtitle` VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
  `guid` VARCHAR (400) NOT NULL,
  `clientJobId` VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
  `company` VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
  `location` VARCHAR (250) NOT NULL,
  `jobdescription_html` TEXT,
  `parsedjobdescription` VARCHAR (50000) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobtype` VARCHAR (25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `logo` VARCHAR (255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyUrl` VARCHAR (255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salary` VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `salaryEstimate` VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `postalCode` VARCHAR (20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `occupationalcategory` VARCHAR (150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `latitude` VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `longitude` VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `maincategory` VARCHAR (25) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titleToTitle` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `titleToSkills` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `descToTitle` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `genericKeywords` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `companyKeywords` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locationKeywords` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `googleFilter` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `careerCluster` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `industry` VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `employerId` VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `job_status` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '1',
  `jobUrl` VARCHAR (255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_valid_desc` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `cleansed_title` VARCHAR (250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cleansed_location` VARCHAR (250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `uniqueId` VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted_date` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `validThrough` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_date` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `job_search_for` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobs_in_demand` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobs_interested` VARCHAR (500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `posted_to_gfj` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `reposted_to_gfj` INT (11) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_from_gfj` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_date_from_gfj` DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlc_unique_check` VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlc_duplicate` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_updated` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `is_deleted` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `deleted_on` DATE DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_expansion` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `sponosored_job` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT '0',
  `city` VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `is_cached` SMALLINT (4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `state` VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country` VARCHAR (100) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 DEFAULT NULL,
  `stage_abbr` VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `country_abbr` VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `redirectUrl` VARCHAR (400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `submittedUrl` VARCHAR (400) DEFAULT NULL,
  `generic_title_id` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `check_parsed` INT (11) DEFAULT '0',
  `updated_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `similarjob_status` TINYINT (1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `similarjob` json NOT NULL,
  `batch_id` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentUniqueId` VARCHAR (100) DEFAULT 'Null',
  `randomId` VARCHAR (50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `locExpand` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `tlExpand` TINYINT (1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `jobdescription_opt` TEXT,
  `custom_logo` VARCHAR (255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `cleansed_jobtitle` VARCHAR (250) DEFAULT NULL,
  `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `TLC` (`tlc_unique_check`),
  KEY `idx_uniqueId` (`uniqueId`),
  KEY `idx_posted_date` (`posted_date`),
  KEY `idx_company_logo` (`company`,`custom_logo`),
  KEY `idx_locexpand_jobid` (`locExpand`,`clientJobId`),
  KEY `idx_guid_empid` (`guid`,`employerId`),
  KEY `idx_gfj_deleted` (`posted_to_gfj`,`is_deleted`),
  KEY `idx_po_code_cntry_cty` (`postalCode`,`country`,`city`),
  KEY `idx_jobstatus_location_jobtitle` (`job_status`,`location`,`jobtitle`),
  KEY `idx_jobstatus_jobtitle` (`job_status`,`jobtitle`),
  KEY `idx_is_updated_is_deleted` (`is_updated`,`is_deleted`),
  KEY `idx_sponosored_job` (`sponosored_job`),
  KEY `idx_locexp_smljob_status` (`locExpand`,`similarjob_status`),
  KEY `idx_deleted_locExpand_title_city_state` (`is_deleted`,`locExpand`,`jobtitle`,`city`,`state`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11853196 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Comment: @ysth
created the new question, could you please help me with this?

Comment: Can you delete some of the indexes? if there are too many indexes it will take more time

Comment: Mostly the indexes are created as per the requirement. @wu hoyt

Comment: You should remove indexes Idx_delfgfjpost, idx_is_updated, idx_is_deleted_locExpand_state, may be locExpand, job_status too, cuz they are like boolean values, and not very selective for the rows

Comment: generally you should not create more than 6 indexes in one table

Comment: If you create index on a row that holds boolean values, then it will reduce the cost time in half, cuz you know there is just a two-level binary tree, split all the data in two parts, not very efficient.

Comment: @wuhoyt, I've updated the current structure of the table, there were a few indexes dropped and a few changes. Could you please suggest which indexes should be dropped?
or can we make any changes in the update query to have a better performance?

Comment: idx_is_updated_is_deleted , idx_jobstatus_jobtitle idx_jobstatus_location_jobtitle, idx_locexpand_jobid, idx_locexp_smljob_status, idx_deleted_locExpand_title_city_state

Answer (score 0):

1. it will take a lot of time if you are updating value of a indexed field
2. split you sql into smaller pieces, and check where is the problem
3. I think you should check the cost time of these query **with or without** index on is_updated

```
select id, is_updated from jobs_feed where is_updated IN(1,2);

update jobs_feed set is_updated=0 where id in (**return of select**);

select id from jobs_feed WHERE is_updated = 0 AND is_deleted = 0

UPDATE  jobs_feed SET is_deleted=1, job_status=3 ,
deleted_on='2022-08-05'  WHERE id in (**return of select**);
```